# Match number at the start of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I am working on a data science project in which i need to extract number of hours from column 'content duration' which has instances like '2.5 hours'. 
I tried running the following code :

```
df['num_hours'] = df['content_duration'].str.extract('(^\d*)')
```

But output of this returns "2" which means it excludes everything after "." 
also, some instances of 'content duration' are like '39 hours' so extract only 39

So, how to extract everything except string in the column 'content duration' ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample string from which you would like to extract from?

Comment: that can work but not sure about other samples ```\d*\.\d+```

Comment: ('^\d*.\d*')  This works well .

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to extract a number that comes at the start of a string, that may or may not include a decimal point.

If you know that the data is cleanly formatted (all input is guaranteed to be valid) then `^([\d.]+)` would work. This will match all digit characters and '.' characters at the start of the string. Given that the first token of the input will only have one decimal point and otherwise consists of digits, this should match what you want.